# Debug crashes in "pythonw.exe"

Tags: python, sockets, debugging, pyqt5

I am working on a very complex project in Python which may crash under the test of a "Crazy Driver". There have been some crashes in the past that seemed stochastic to me at first sight. To verify this I stepped into the role of a "Crazy Driver" and voila, it crashes everytime. There is sadly no exception raised.

My conditions are the following.

- Windows 7
- Anaconda 4.3.30

  - Python 2.7.13
  - PyQt 5.6
  - Spyder 3.2.4

I cannot show any real source code for I am using it professionally. So will try to explain the problem I see and my results so far. In this project I am using `PyQt5` and `socket` in a client software. In the GUI there is a button to establish the connection to a server.

```
def onConnect(self) :
    if self.connected :
         self.somethread.terminate()

         # Do resetting

         self.buttonConnect.setText("Connect")
         self.connected = False

         return

    try :
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(("the.server.anywhere", PORT))
        self.sock.send("Some Information")
        buff = self.sock.recv(1024)

        # Work with the buffer

        self.buttonConnect.setText("Disconnect")
        self.connected = True

        self.some_thread = myThread(args)   # Class inherited from QThread
        self.some_thread.start()

    except socket.error :
        # Log the exception
```

When I am now fast clicking this button repeatedly, after some iterations the GUI freezes. After closing the GUI the IPython Console says `Kernel died`. Might it be the case that there are some problems with the timing and the underlaying communication and threading? How can I debug this? My concern if I use `pdb` or `ipdb` I will not get any information.

Comment: Have you tried running your code outside of spyder/Anaconda? I've encountered certain types of errors before that will crash and burn in an environment like spyder or PyCharm, but will print a stack trace and exit gracefully when run from python on the command line.

Comment: @user3419537: I use PyInstaller to build a binary file from my script. I first encountered the crashes in those builds. They occur the same way.

Comment: Since you are using `PyQt` I would take a guess that you probably have an [unhandled exception](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#unhandled-python-exceptions) in a slot somewhere. This will cause the program to abort in the way you described. You can install an [exception hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?#sys.excepthook) to intercept the exception and print some debugging info. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488660/3419537) for an example